No dedicated bus bar for neutral
If my bus bars are connected in some way in my subpanel can I still connect my neutral? I’m not sure if I can connect it like this.


Yes this is the sub panel I don’t have that neutral connection hooked to anything yet I figured it wasn’t going to be good so besides the neutral what other problems do you see. ️

Then there's the question of where those wires tapped into the main feed lines go... I guess those black lumps might be some sort of in-line fuse holder - whether they are ones that pass code for the use I have no idea, but it's an unusual sight, anyways.

Having two wires in the lugs feeding into the main breaker is a code violation (should only be one). What's the box below the panel that the red and black wires go into?

Where is this sub-panel located? Is it in the same building as your main panel, or an outbuilding?

You have dedicated bus bars for neutral. What you lack, and apparently now need if this is a sub-panel (unless it's grandfathered from long ago and you love living dangerously rather than bringing it up to modern standards) is one or more dedicated grounding bus bars. Do NOT attempt to disassemble the bar bonding the neutral bars. Add a compatible grounding bar kit.
This appears to have been a 240V only panel with no neutrals, so the lack of a separate neutral and ground bus bar was not an issue (until that one cable with a white wire connected to the neutral bus and the black to a {newly added?} single pole breaker on the bottom. I assume this is your proposed new circuit.) But if you don't make it a 4-wire feed, [Hot, Hot, Neutral and Ground, separately] and it's NOT old enough to be grandfathered, you cannot connect loads that need neutral here.
Depending on the exact type of the cable feeding it, (read that off the side of the cable, and edit into your question) you may be able to retrofit a ground conductor (depends on the cable type being one where the bare copper wrapped around the other two is supposed to be neutral) which is permitted since NEC 2014.

The QO breakers without a yellow stamp are ooooold. Odds are pretty decent that the three-wire (combined neutral/ground wire) was legal when installed.

Since this is a QO, it shouldn't be too hard to find grounding bar kits for even.  Also, the double tapped line lugs need to be fixed something terrible

You either need to replace the feeder and add a ground bar, or if you don't need to replace the feeder then all you need is a bonding screw to bond the neutral bars to the cabinet.
I assume this not in a detached building because it appears that when installed there where no 120v loads.
If installed when and where you could ground via the neutral then the grounds and neutrals would need to be bonded, so just a screw needed.
Most likely-> If installed when and where the ground and neutral needed to be separate then the 3 wire SE Cable with bare neutral is used as a 240v feeder the bare wire can only be used as a ground, so a bonding screw to the can would ground the can. When this panel was installed no provision for 120v loads was made. You will need to run 120 circuits from another panel or refeed the panel with 4 conductor cable and then you would need separate new ground bars. No provision is allowed to use this bare as a ground and run a wild neutral to the source panel.
